# DreamSpark Windows 7 download is stuck as a SDC file

Tags: dreamspark

I recently got DreamSpark from my college. I'm trying to download Windows 7 on my PC (currently on Vista).

I followed the instructions: I downloaded the secure download manager, and then tried to download the file. It reached 100% twice, and now has a launch button, but when I go to where its downloaded it's still an SDC file.

What do I do next?

Comment: @Xavierjazz *"DreamSpark is a Microsoft program to provide students with software design and development tools at no charge."* - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DreamSpark)

Comment: The title is miss leading and doesn't match the question

Comment: The DreamSpark download process can be very confusing. (I use it just infrequently enough to forget the gotchas each time). The primary problem is that the "Launch" button takes you to the Download folder but NOT to the folder where the ISO file has been created. (And if, like me, your Downloads folder is packed with dozens of items, it can be very hard to find it.) But as @gronostaj commented below, look for a new SUB-folder with appropriate name (eg. Windows 7 Professional...)

Comment: @Xavierjazz Did you remove your first comment? I see you're thanking Gronostaj for quoting from Wikipedia what DreamSpark is. But I can't see why. If possible, please keep your comments for later reference.

Comment: @kmote It's not confusing. It's pretty straight forward. You just need to understand the process. The "Launch" button takes you to the specified download folder, and this is the same folder where you find your ISO or EXE or any other file that's the actual binary content of your software download. You can open Explorer and navigate to the download location manually, if it's less confusing. (It might also help to sort out the junk in your downloads folder.)

Comment: Aaron, you need to try downloading your software once again. Make sure you have a stable Internet connection, and the latest version of the SDM. Also, be patient when the download is in progress, don't interrupt it, or else it will produce those SDC files in your specified download folder.

Comment: I had no previous comment, I was just grateful at the time.

Answer (score 1):

SDM downloads files to a path specified at the top:

[image: Screenshot of SDM with path marked]

A new folder with downloaded files will appear in that directory when the download is finished.

Comment: The location is set to my downloads folder and thats where the sdk file is.

Comment: That file doesn't matter, it's just your digital purchase proof. It should stay there after download. Look for a new folder with appropriate name (eg. *Windows 7 Professional...*)

Answer (score 0):

There are three components that are used in the download process when you download Microsoft software from a DreamSpark web store.

- SDM — Secure Download Manager
- SDX — Secure Download (eXchange?)
- SDC — Secure Download (Cache?)

Frankly, I don't know the exact meaning of the X and C in the abbreviations above. I'm just guessing here, but I believe I am right about what the idea is behind these files.

The **SDM** is obviously the Secure Download Manager. This program relies on Internet Explorer. It basically functions like an Internet Explorer shell. It serves three purposes. It authorizes your download, it downloads your software, and it verifies your download.

The **SDX** file contains authorization and hash information. You need this file to initiate the download. So make sure to keep this file. You can reuse it whenever you need to download your software. You can use it even when the software you have downloaded has been removed from the web store. So I recommend that you keep this file, don't delete it.

The **SDC** file is a temporary file. While the download is in progress, SDM is downloading to the SDC file. *(You can compare this to the .part files that Firefox browser uses during downloads.)* Once the download has completed, it basically renames this file to what it's supposed to be named as and moves it to the download folder that's specified in the SDM.

The SDC file is not placed in the download folder. Normally! So you should not be seeing them in the download folder you specified in the SDM. I have not confirmed but I think it's placed in the AppData folder. Once the download has completed, it is renamed and moved to the download folder you specified in SDM. If you have not specified a folder manually, it will be set to use your Downloads folder in your Windows user folder.

This is my understanding of how this works.

1. User runs SDM_EN.msi and SDM installs itself.
2. SDM is installed in `%localappdata%\Local\e-academy
   Inc\SecureDownloadManager`
3. User opens 123456789.sdx
4. The SDX file opens in SDM.
5. SDM authorizes and starts downloading to a temporary SDC file in
   `%localappdata%\Local\e-academy Inc\SecureDownloadManager`
6. SDM checks the hash of SDC file
7. SDM renames the SDC file and moves it (or copies it) to
   `%userprofile%\Downloads`
8. (SDM may or may not create any additional subfolders in the
   specified download folder. This depends on the software packaging.)

The fact that you see the SDC file in your download folder could only mean one thing. Your download was interrupted! One of possibly three things could have interrupted the download. You could have aborted the download yourself, and then restarted it. Your authorization or hash information didn't match at the end of the process. You could also have a bad Internet connection.

I wouldn't recommend that you try to convert the SDC file to the much needed ISO file. Simply because the SDC file could have hash mismatch and hence corrupted. Just make sure your Internet connection is working as expected. Try downloading using a different computer or a network card, or a different Internet connection.

If you still want to try converting the SDC file to ISO, just rename the SDC file by replacing "SDC" with "ISO" in the file name so that the file name, with extension becomes e.g. `123456789.iso`. But I don't recommend it. It could work at first try, but you might encounter errors later on, e.g. when you try booting from the media you create with this ISO file or during Windows installation.